# Entity Framework / Linq doesn't know to deserialize object?

Tags: c#, json, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 3 classes:

```
public class Widget 
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public List<WidgetConfig> Configs {get; set;}
     public LabelConfig LabelConfig {get; set;}
}

public class WidgetConfig 
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public string JsonValue {get; set;}
}

public class LabelConfig 
{
     public int Type {get; set;}
     public string Color {get; set;}
     public object Value {get; set;}
}
```

Entities and Dtos match, so I'll extract one widget so:

```
var model = await dataContext.Widgets
      .Includes(x => x.Configs)
      .Select(x => new Dtos.Widget() {
         Id = x.Id,
         Name = x.Name,
         Configs = x.Configs.Select(y => new Dtos.WidgetConfig() {
            Id = y.Id,
            Name = y.Name,
            JsonValue = y.JsonValue
         }).ToList(),
         LabelConfig = x.Name == "Test"
             ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LabelConfig>(x.Configs[0].JsonValue)
             : null
        }).ToListAsync();
```

`Newtonsoft.Json` is used for converting json. I want to calculate directly `Widget.LabelConfig` attribute, but this will be null every time.

If I try to convert it after using EF, this will get correct data:

```
  var jsonValue = model.Configs[0].JsonValue;
  var convertedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LabelConfig>(jsonValue);
  model.LabelConfig = convertedObject;
```

Is it an EF / Linq issue or I do something wrong?

Comment: 1) what error are you getting? please add it 2) if understood everything correctly, EF does not know how to convert `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LabelConfig>` into valid SQL.

Comment: I don't get any error, just my value is all time null if I try to convert it directly inside of Select(). No valid SQL, is a json value saved as string in database and now I try to convert it into my object LabelConfig. I don't think that is an value iaaue because second example convert it correctly. Logical expression can be possible to be false all time? But I checked it (x.Name == "Test")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the way EF core works and the way you have your query structured. EF core will convert anything before a "hydrating" statement to SQL, but it doesn't know what to do with your LabelConfig statement. However, once you run it through `ToListAsync()`, the entities become in-memory objects and LINQ can work as you would expect. So what you need to do is pull the raw data and store it in a string, then convert it after it's been pulled into memory. That can be done by selecting into a new anonymous object that holds your Widget and the string, passing `ToList()` once to hydrate, then selecting out of THAT object with the JSON expression to fill it in.

Comment: thanks, your explanations helped me to understand how EF treat this problem.